# While loop to modify multiple elements in a nested loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to change multiple elements in this nested list game board using a while loop `getInput(myList)` but the loop doesn't stop when I input 'q'

```
def firstBoard():
    rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows: "))
    col = int(input("Please enter the number of columns: "))
    myList = [[0]*col for i in range(rows)]
    return myList
def getInput(myList):
    rows = input("Enter the row or 'q': ")
    col = input("enter the column: ")
    while rows != "q":
        rows = input("Enter the row or 'q': ")
        col = input("Enter the column: ")
        myList[int(rows)-1][int(col)-1] = "X"

    return myList

def printBoard(myList):
    for n in myList:
        for s in n:
            print(s, end= " ")

def main():
    myList = firstBoard()
    myList = getInput(myList)
    printBoard(myList)
main()
```

For example if i'd want my output to end up like this:

```
X 0 0 0 0
0 X 0 0 0
0 0 X 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When entering 'q' you are not immediately exiting your loop and you are trying to cast to a int('q'), which throws an exception. You could replace it with:

```
def getInput(myList):
    while True:
        rows = input("Enter the row or 'q': ")
        if rows == 'q':
            break
        col = input("Enter the column: ")
        myList[int(rows)-1][int(col)-1] = "X"
    return myList
```

This also fixes the fact you ignored the first entries.
You may also need an extra print in your printBoard() or the whole board will be printed on one line.